# javascript callback when some scripts in the page have executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-callback

I'm trying to add a loading modal to an HTML page while some javascript are executing. My problem is that I can't get to notice when these scripts have finished executing.

I've tried with:

```
$.when(
    $.getScript( "/script1.js" ),
    $.getScript( "/script2.js" ),
    $.getScript( "/script3.js" ),
    $.Deferred(function( deferred ){
        $( deferred.resolve );
    })
).done(function(){
    console.log('everything have been executed!');
});
```

But as the [getScript JQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) says:

> The callback is fired once the script has been loaded but not necessarily executed.

Is there a way to set a callback for such event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using $.ajax to load the scripts.

```
$.ajax({
    async:false,
    url:'/script.js',
    type:'GET',
    data:null,
    dataType:'script',
    success:function(){
        console.log('Executed')
    }
});
```

async needs to be false, so that it loads and executes the script first, before running the success function.

Comment: `$.getScript` is actually using the `$.ajax` method. It is just a shorthand. The problem of the OP is not loading the script obviously. It's rather knowing if a function in the lazy loaded script got executed.

Comment: @DavidDomain async is false my answer, which means it loads and executes the script first, then performs the success function, while with $.getScript async is true. I edited the original answer to make it more clear.

Comment: Async false is deprecated. [Synchronous and asynchronous requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests)

Comment: I don't think you need `async:false` for the script to execute first, just `dataType: 'script'`... See [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#data-types) for data type `script`.